# How to search a property in a list of beans?

Tags: java, collections, dictionary, javabeans, apache-commons

I have a list of Order objects -

```
class Order {
Date date;
float amount;
String companyCode;
}
List<Order> orders = /* Initialize with list of order objects with valid data */
```

I have a list of Company objects -

```
class Company {
String name;
String code;
String address;
}
List<Company> companies = /* Initialize with list of company objects with valid data */
```

I need a to create a map of companyCode and name.

Is there some library that would allow me to write code like this (where BeanSearch is the hypothetical library class)?

```
Map<String, String> codeAndName = new HashMap<String, String>();
for(Order o: orders) {
   codeAndName.put(o.getCompanyCode(), 
                   BeanSearch.find(companies, "code", o.getCompanyCode).getName());
}
```

Alternatively is there another good way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils.html should work for you right?  Specifically you can use the find method